# Work around AWS assume_role session expiration

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm calling 4 actions from AWS Health API to collect all the findings using these loopy loops (I removed some DynamoDB pieces to make it clearer). The issue is that the script takes quite some time to run and ends up timing out after an hour because of the `ExpiredTokenException`. I already tried the `DurationSeconds`, and it's fixed at 3600.

Can I work around this somehow? Like splitting the function into multiple functions? Or that wouldn't work at all?

```
sts = boto3.client('sts')
# use STS to AssumeRole for the Organization Health Account
memberAcct = sts.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::x:role/Health-Role',RoleSessionName='xacct-health')
# retrieve creds from member account to create new Health Boto3 Client
xAcctAccessKey = memberAcct['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
xAcctSecretKey = memberAcct['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
xAcctSeshToken = memberAcct['Credentials']['SessionToken']
health = boto3.client('health',aws_access_key_id=xAcctAccessKey,aws_secret_access_key=xAcctSecretKey,aws_session_token=xAcctSeshToken)

def health_collect():
    try:
        paginator = health.get_paginator('describe_events_for_organization')
        iterator = paginator.paginate()
        for page in iterator:
            for e in page['events']:
                eventArn = str(e['arn'])
                healthEventScope = str(e['eventScopeCode'])
                if healthEventScope == 'ACCOUNT_SPECIFIC':
                    affectedAccounts = health.describe_affected_accounts_for_organization(eventArn=eventArn)['affectedAccounts']
                    for affectedAcctId in affectedAccounts:
                        eventDetails = health.describe_event_details_for_organization(
                            organizationEventDetailFilters=[
                                {
                                    'eventArn': eventArn,
                                    'awsAccountId': affectedAcctId
                                }
                            ]
                        )
                        eventDescription = str(eventDetails['successfulSet'][0]['eventDescription']['latestDescription'])
                        entityDetails = health.describe_affected_entities_for_organization(
                            organizationEntityFilters=[
                                {
                                    'eventArn': eventArn,
                                    'awsAccountId': affectedAcctId
                                }
                            ]
                        )
                        entityValue = str(entityDetails['entities'][0]['entityValue'])
                        if entityValue == 'AWS_ACCOUNT':
                            entityValue = affectedAcctId
                        else:
                else:
                    affectedAccounts = 'ALL'
                    entityArn = 'NOT_SPECIFIC'
                    entityValue = 'NOT_SPECIFIC'
                    eventDetails = health.describe_event_details_for_organization(organizationEventDetailFilters=[{'eventArn': eventArn}])
                    eventDescription = str(eventDetails['successfulSet'][0]['eventDescription']['latestDescription'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

health_collect()
```

Comment: The maximum lifetime (DurationSeconds) for temporary credentials can be up to 12 hours, but there are two caveats...


1. the IAM role needs to be configured to allow a longer limit, since the default maximum is something smaller (2 hour? 2 hours?)

2. Boto3 (and the "aws" CLI) are a bit of a PITA when it comes to setting the limit longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already issues on GitHub for this problem.

[refreshing sts role assumption credentials for long running operations #443](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/443)

[Automatically use RefreshableCredentials when appropriate #2158](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/2158)

Meanwhile, there is some intermediate workaround, I think you can have via [RefreshableCredentials](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/credentials.py#L360) class in the botocore combined with [get_session](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/session.py#L1034) method.

```py
...

def assumed_session(role_arn, session_name, session=None):

    if session is None:
        session = Session()

    def refresh():
     # call assume role and return a dict of
     # access_key
     # secret
     # token

    session_credentials = RefreshableCredentials.create_from_metadata(
        metadata=refresh(),
        refresh_using=refresh,
        method='sts-assume-role')

    s = get_session()
    s._credentials = session_credentials
    region = session._session.get_config_variable('region') or 'us-east-1'
    s.set_config_variable('region', region)
    return Session(botocore_session=s)
```

a working version of the above code can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kapilt/ac8e222081f63ba64e93)

Comment: Does this actually replace/refresh creds in `~/.aws/credentials`?

Answer (score 1):

I just got off a call with AWS Enterprise Support. I can only speak for `boto3` `1.34.29` or higher. I read the link in the other answer about how there is a bug in boto3 so I called up AWS to confirm if they are aware of this issue. And they said that you can indeed specify 43200 seconds (12 hour) as a max from the api (which boto3 sdk uses) or cli. When they mentioned this, I did some research and I found the following in the boto3 1.34.29 documentation (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts/client/assume_role.html):

> The duration, in seconds, of the role session. The value specified can
> range from 900 seconds (15 minutes) up to the maximum session duration
> set for the role.

First, let’s analyze that statement: the maximum session duration set for the role. What does it mean? If you look in the IAM Console and select your specified role, you will notice in the console the editable option: Maximum session duration. You must first configure this to the maximum of 12 hours, like I show in this screenshot:

[image]

**boto3 will only go to the max defined in the “Maximum session duration”.**

Now read this line in the boto3 docs:

> The maximum session duration setting can have a value from 1 hour to
> 12 hours. If you specify a value higher than this setting or the
> administrator setting (whichever is lower), the operation fails. For
> example, if you specify a session duration of 12 hours, but your
> administrator set the maximum session duration to 6 hours, your
> operation fails.

Keep that in mind, but also take heed of the fact that you can indeed specify a 12 hour limit. One other important part I want to highlight:

> Role chaining limits your Amazon Web Services CLI or Amazon Web
> Services  API role session to a maximum of one hour. When you use the
> AssumeRole API operation to assume a role, you can specify the
> duration of your role session with the DurationSeconds parameter. You
> can specify a parameter value of up to 43200 seconds (12 hours),
> depending on the maximum session duration setting for your role.

Basically, you can achieve the 12 hour max if you are assuming a role without role chaining. So if you are an IAM User and you are assuming a role, and then you assume another role which you use the assume_role method, then you are restricted to 1 hour. Ultimately, your code can have something like this:

```
sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=role_arn,
    RoleSessionName="ATG",
    DurationSeconds=43200 
)
```

As long as you are using a newer boto3 version like 1.34.29, then there is no bug. You can directly use the assume_role API. I am not saying not to use credential refresh, but if you are running for 12 hours, then this is also an option.